# Convert a string to one hot encoding matrix and then feed to neural network

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have many DNA sequence data, which has been read into *xtrain*. Each sample has a label (classification problem), which has been read into *ytrain*.

```py
tokenizer = keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(char_level=True, lower=True)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts("ATCGN")
# number of distinct characters, should be 5 in this case
max_id = len(tokenizer.word_index) 
print(tokenizer.word_index)
```

{'a': 1, 't': 2, 'c': 3, 'g': 4, 'n': 5}

one sequence data looks like: "---ATCGATN---".

I want to split each sequence into fixed length (e.g., 4) sub-seq. Take the seq above as an example: "ATCG", "TCGA", "CGAT", "GATN". Each seq will be represented by one row in the matrix. Then using one hot encoding to represent each character. So, "A" is something like [0,0,0,0,1], "T" is something like [0,0,0,1,0]. Concatenating all encodings for each chars in the sequence gives us the encoding for the sub-seq. So, "ATCG" will be something like [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,...]
In this way, each sequence will be turned into a matrix of size (number_of_sub-seq, len_of_sub-seq * 5), where 5 comes from tokenizer.word_index.

The following code tries to accomplish this. I am pretty new to Tensorflow, so I cannot figure out how to convert each type into others or print out the real values of tensors. For the code `[x_encoded] = np.array(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([x])) - 1` gives me an error of AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'lower'.

```py
def seq2mat(x, y):
  x = tf.strings.regex_replace(x, "-", "")
  x = tf.strings.regex_replace(x, 'K', 'N')

  [x_encoded] = np.array(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([x])) - 1
  x_dataset = x_dataset.window(kmer_len, shift=3, drop_remainder=True)
  x_flat = x_dataset.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(kmer_len))
  x_1hot = x_flat.map(lambda kmer: tf.one_hot(kmer, depth=max_id))
  
  # try to stack them into a matrix
  x_np_mat = []
  for item in x_1hot:
    line = np.array(item)
    x_np_mat.append(line.flatten())
  x_np_mat = np.array(x_np_mat)
  return x_np_mat

batch_size = 8
kmer_len = 8
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xtrain, ytrain))
train_data = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1000, seed=1)
train_data = train_data.map(seq2mat)
train_data = train_data.batch(batch_size).prefetch(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tokenizer = keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(char_level=True, lower=True)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts("ATCGN")
x = []
seq = np.array(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences('ATCGN'))
a = keras.utils.to_categorical(seq[:,0]-1)
for i in a:
  x = x + list(i)
print(x)
```

Comment: Hi Malavika, thanks for your answer. However, this is not something I am looking for. I guess I did not make myself clear in the problem. `train_data` has been converted to tf.data.Dataset and thus tokenizer.texts_to_sequences does not work directly on string. Instead, it is currently working on a Tensor with dtype="string". This is the point where it throws an error. Hope I am clear this time.